# Manual CakePHP validation issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to validate a field manually through `beforeValidate`:

In `Post` Model:

```
function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    $p = Router::getParams();
    //if it is step 3
    if ($p['pass'][0] == '3') {
        //if the user hasn't chosen any subject
        if (empty($this->data['Student'][0]['Subject'])) {

            $this->validationErrors['Student'][0]['Subject'] = 'Your error message';
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I checked with debugKit that it is passed to `PostController`.

```
array(
    'Student' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Subject' => 'Your error message'
        )
    )
)
```

But when I tried to echo it in the view nothing shows..

```
<?php echo $this->Form->error('Student.0.Subject'); ?>
```

EDIT:

At last, I echo the error message manually by passing it from controller to the view:

```
$this->set('error', $this->Post->validationErrors);
```

But `$this->Post->validationErrors` overwrites all other data that is stored in the same key..

Comment: $this->set('manualError', $this->Post->validationErrors);

Comment: Ya but the original data got overwritten whenever I call beforeValidate

Comment: `$p = Router::getParams();` in beforeValidate? I think you should take a huge step back and ask/think about what you're trying to achieve. Models shouldn't know anything about the request except what they are told; You should be validating _the model data_ if what you need isn't in the model data _put it in the model data_. Currently: so wrong.